# AngularJS - load values from api in module config block

Tags: angularjs

I have a Facebook login button in my app that uses 'angular-facebook' module. In my `.config` block I have following code:

```
FacebookProvider.init('myAppId');
```

Now I have service that is loading `myAppId` from DB via REST api but I dont know how to correctly load it and pass it in `.config` block.

I spent last 2 hours reading manuals angd googling how to do this but I am still confused how to make this work.

Comment: Paste some code in your question and show us what you have done so far.

Comment: The question is quite simple an I assume you know how Angular service looks like.

Comment: you can implement provider recipe so you can use it in your app's config phase. here is fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/jugnu_pathak/Le4qqz5b/2/

Comment: Ok got it working now, I had to learn a little more about provider and promises :-) Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can retreive the $http service by using angular injector, and then, configure your app, something like this :

```
(function() {


     angular.element(document).ready(function() {
           var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
           var $http = initInjector.get("$http"); 

            $http.get("/myFbAppId.json").then(function(response) {
               angular
                  .module('myApp')
                  .config(function(facebookProvider){
                      FacebookProvider.init(response.data.myAppId);
                  })  

                  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
            })

     });

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks in order to prevent instantiating services before they have been fully configured. You basically can only inject providers and constants in your config block. So the only solution is not to do it in a config block but in a run block.

Comment: Thanks, so if I use some library that requires init values for its provider in config block there is no way to load these from api somehow?